# Teradata - run a file/script at Unix Linux command prompt

Tags: unix, client, teradata, automated-deploy

I have the client/TTU installed on Unix box for Teradata.

If I do the following, it works. Where "..." is Teradata BTEQ normal output and once the following is done, I'm back at the prompt.

**$ bteq**

...
....

```
. logon dbname/dbuser,dbpassword
SELECT DATE, TIME;
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
```

..
...
**$**

Now, lets say I put the following lines in a file called "***testtd.bteq***"

```
. logon dbname/dbuser,$dbpassword
SELECT DATE, TIME;
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
```

What I want now is ... how can I run this script (.bteq) at Unix $ prompt ???

I tried the following methods so far, but they didn't work, may be Im missing anything: 
1. bteq < /path/to/testtd.bteq > testtd.log
2. bteq <
.run /path/to/testtd.bteq
HereDocEndsHere

Any ideas? DO I HAVE to provide ". logon dbname/dbuser,dbpassword" FIRST, if I'm using the HereDocument way?

Running bteq command on $ prompt doesn't even give me any HELP/options that I can use, like other commands.

i.e.
cmd -u user -p password -f file etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS - It works via method 1 -- when I hard code the password in the script file for LOGON command.

I wanted to do the same via exporting a variable called "dbpassword"

i.e.

$ export dbpassword=xyxyxyxyx

and

then, inside the script file, i can use "$dbpassword" ... in the LOGON command.. somehow export is not exporting the var within .bteq logon command.

Comment: Yeah I guess you will have your login credentials somewhere.  There's no work around that.  Using keys instead is the proper solution, but I have no idea if your `bteq` is capable of such.

Comment: I think too. HereDoc way is working if I'm within my shell script and doing the following: bteq << then on next line, . logon $a/$b,$c ..... " this works as if a, b and c are exported. But, if the logon command is in the .bteq itself, it's not working.

Comment: Seems like I need to tweak the .bteq file into a dummy runtime file and substitute the keyword "$dbpassword" with real password value and then pass that instead of actual .bteq and then delete that dummy file.

Comment: I recommend keeping a `.tdlogon` file in your home folder with your username and password, with the following contents: `.logon databaseName/username,password` From there, you can start your `bteq` code with `.run file=$HOME/.tdlogon` and you'll be logged in.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice I'm aware of is

1. store your teradata credentials in a `~/.tdlogon` file
2. create a script that contains your `bteq` call with all the stuff it needs.

E.g., create a file `bteqScript.sh` with

```
/* define helper variables, e.g.... */
export ARCHIVEDIR=~/data
export DATAFILE=dataOutput1.txt
bteq <<EOF
.run file=$HOME/.tdlogon
.export data file=${ARCHIVEDIR}|${DATAFILE} 
/* sql code on next line(s) */
select 
    'foo' as "bar"
; 
.export reset
EOF
```

Note that `.run file=...` executes the .logon command with your credentials, stored elsewhere.

Kudos to [Alex Hasha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1241152/alex-hasha) for the bteq script.